# Sonarlint for VScode update binding "connect mode"

Tags: visual-studio-code, sonarlint

I am not being able to download the "quality profile" from sonarqube server. And also y am not really understand, how i could update the profile if something changes on the server. The documentation said:

> To have rules, issues and exclusions synched. First configure the connection via user settings (SonarLint section), and then bind the project in workspace settings. If the server-side config changes, you can trigger a local update Update SonarLint binding to SonarQube/SonarCloud command on the command palette.

But i do not know, what command i have to use to update the binding.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my working workspace setting,

```
{
    "sonarlint.connectedMode.project": {
        "serverId": "BF41A1F2-AWjgtrls5CwHEOrWfhs8",    // Connection defined in sonarlint.connectedMode.servers
        "projectKey": "project"                 // Project key in SonarQube/SonarCloud
    },
    "sonarlint.connectedMode.servers": [
        {
            "serverId": "BF41A1F2-AWjgtrls5CwHEOrWfhs8", // Connection identifier
            "serverUrl": "http://localhost:9000",   // SonarQube/SonarCloud URL - https//sonarcloud.io for SonarCloud
            "token": "4a53d5342382a9079369f0fb9e46bd14b2f479a4"    // User token - generated in SonarQube/SonarCloud in My Account>Security
        }
    ]
}
```